# How to set https as default?

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I have installed ssl in my hosting. Now http and https both are working. I need to keep https as default. If the user type www.sitename.com , then it will work as https://sitename.com. please help.

Answer (score 1):

Pls add the following rules

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R,L]

If you are using ECE2 instance pls.. enable rewrite module.